# I am not able to see path for Chromedriver on running selenium function

Tags: r, web-scraping, path, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I try to run the following command:

`selenium_object <- selenium(retcommand = T, check = F)`

and get the following output on running 'selenium_object'

"C:\PROGRA~1\AZULJA~1\JDK\bin\java.exe character(0) -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\binman\binman_geckodriver\win64\0.33.0/geckodriver.exe" -Dphantomjs.binary.path="C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\binman\binman_phantomjs\windows\2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe" -jar "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\binman\binman_seleniumserver\generic\4.0.0-alpha-2/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar" -port 4567"

It can be seen that binman_chromedriver path is not shown here, even if it exists in the Local folder.

I believe because of this I am unable to run following commands like:

`remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "119.0.6045.105",verbose = F,port = free_port())`

which is giving me an error:

"Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2224 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "119.0.6045.105", verbose = F,  :
Could not determine server status."

My current chrome version is 119.0.6045.200, so 119.0.6045.105 should work and should not be the problem.

Please let me know where I am going wrong (if I am at all!)